Jitosol not showing me any interest
Traded sol for jitosol but interest is not showing up on phantom wallet I staked with jito network

I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't really focus on anything that is generally helpful to the page regarding Solana developer issues.

Interest does not show up in phantom, the price of jitoSOL will slowly increase over time as staking rewards accrue. When you want to harvest your interest, swap jitoSOL back to SOL and you should have more SOL than you started with. Be careful of slippage and temporary price fluctuations, if the price looks wrong, give it some time for arbitragers to come in. You can also directly unstake via the Jito interface (https://www.jito.network/staking/) but it may take up to 2.5 days.

I also find this very suspicious and confusing.  I switched my SOL to JitoSOL about 3 months ago.  I've watched the $ of JitoSOL stay a certain amount above SOL the whole time however it goes back down and that confuses me.  For example this last week when I looked at conversion from my JITOSOL back to SOL it showed me 281.5 shares.  A few days later I checked again it went down to 280 shares.  I checked today and it's down to 279 shares?  Why?  I'm looking at the price right now SOL is 245ish and JSOL is 281 (only $36 higher) when last week it was $40 higher?  I can understand some fluctuation here as things catchup but that difference over a weeks time doesn't make sense to me.  Really making me wonder wither regular staking is better where I know exactly where I stand.
